# Showing that $\int_{0}^{\infty}k(x,z)f(x)dx$ is analytic with $k$ heat kernel.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, heat-equation

Let $k(x,z)=\frac{1}{(4\pi z)^{n/2}}e^{|x|/{4z}}$ heat kernel. Show that $F(z):=\int_{0}^{\infty}k(x,z)f(x)dx$ is analytic, where $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R}.)$

Will there be some theorem that allows us to conclude that, when $k (x, z)$ is analytical, then $F(z)$ is also analytical?

Comment: There are several ways to prove any function is analytic, and most are applicable here.  You can expand $k$ in a power series, then interchange the sum and integral.  You can differentiate under the integral sign and check that the Cauchy-Riemann equation is satisfied.  You can verify Morera's theorem by interchanging integrals.  And so on.

Comment: But the Gauß kernel is NOT analytic at points $(x,0)$ (moreover, it should be $e^{-|x|^2/4z}$).